# Vuejs Router, conditional loading of JavaScript Code

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I am integrating Vue Router into my application.

Within one of my components, I am using some js code which I do not want to load or be present when on another route?

Example

```
compA.vue
<script>console.log('hello')</script>

app.com/a -> I should see console log Hello.

app.com/b -> when I access this I should not see hello in the console.
```

EDIT: Clarifying based on the responses.

I have two components, each with own lifecycle hooks so I do not need to set logic to fire the function based on components...

If a user visits compA and the function fires and creates some side effects, when I visit compB I would like there to be no side effects similar to how a traditional route would work, because it would get the new code and render the page once more.

Comment: After reading your edit, I am a bit confused. What side effects are you exactly talking about? Can you provide some examples? Personally I think you are overthinking it. When going from page to page with vue-router, you load in the component and it's logic when visiting that page. The reason why `Hello` is still visible in the console is that the console did not get a refresh.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @IlyasDeckers however imagine if the first component adds something to the DOM or the some data to the window object - it would still be there, my use case is such that I need it to disappear.

Comment: You cold try to add the `:key="$route.fullPath"` property to `<router-link>` this basically tells Vue to rerender a component when browsing to different pages that uses the same components. Or, I read about a `vm.$forceUpdate();` method some time ago, this basically forces the Vue instance to re-render, but does not affect child components.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the path variable accessible through `$router` in vue. Open your vue devtools, click on your component and click on $route on the righthandside. Here you can see all the variables accessible through `$route`

Example:

```
  mounted() {
    // console.log will only run on route '/a'
    if (this.$route.path === '/a') {
        console.log('Hello World)
    }
  }
```

If `$route` throws an error. You need to define this in your `main.js`

```
  import router from './router'

  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    store,
    render: h => h(App)
  })
```

in `router/index.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Login from '@/app/Login/Login'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Login',
      component: Login
    }
  ]
})
```

Comment: This does not answer the question, I have two components, so I can add the function to the onCreated in them separately I do not need to check in the path.

Answer (score 1):

you can add some meta data to your routing config:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/a',
      component: compA,
      meta: { doLog: true }
    },
    {
      path: '/b',
      component: compA,
      meta: { doLog: false }
    },
  ]
})
```

and then you can use `this.$route.meta.doLog` in your component:

```
created() {
  if(this.$route.meta.doLog) {
     console.log('hello');
  }
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question, as I have two components.